# Improving the speed of loop in javascript for objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a loop that works great, but doing some testing I notice it is a bit slow. I get an average time within the loop of about 0.11 seconds. Include that with some arrays containing a length of over 100 and the time starts making a big difference. So I mainly want to improve the speed of the loop without compromising the functionality it already has (which is taking a JSON object/array and turning it into an html format). Below is the code along with the function that is called within the loop.

```
let replacements = '';
let ind = 0;
for (let w in obj[key]) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[key][w])) {
            if (obj[key].length > 10) {
                replacements += "<font color='green'>Array(" + obj[key].length + ")</font>"
                break
            }
            replacements += ((ind == 0) ? "<font color='green'>Array(" : ", <font color='green'>Array(") + obj[key][w].length + ")</font>";
        } else {
            if (typeof obj[key][w] === 'object') {
                replacements += ((ind == 0) ? "" : ", ") + "{...}";
            } else {
                replacements += ((ind == 0) ? "" : ", ") + ObjectString(obj[key][w], "preview");
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[key][w]) || typeof obj[key][w] === 'object') {
            replacements += ((ind == 0) ? "" : ", ") + w + ": " + ((Array.isArray(obj[key][w])) ? "[...]" : "{...}");
        } else {
            replacements += ((ind == 0) ? "" : ", ") + w + ": ";
            replacements += ObjectString(obj[key][w], "preview");
        }
    }
    ind++;
}

function ObjectString(obj, type) { //~0.001-0.003 seconds
    let objString = obj;
    if (typeof objString == "string" && !objString.match(/<.*?>/g))
        objString = "<font color='red'>\"" + objString + "\"</font>";
    else if (/<.*?>/g.test(objString))
        objString = ((type == "normal") ? "<pre>" + process(objString).replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;') + "</pre>" + objString : "<font color='red'>\"...\"</font>");
    else if (typeof objString == "number" || typeof objString == "boolean")
        objString = "<font color=' #947cf6'>" + objString + "</font>";

    return objString
}


function process(str) {//~0.001 seconds

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str.trim();

    return format(div, 0).innerHTML;
}
```

Hopefully this can be optimized to increase its speed, but if it can't then I would at least like some help to clean it up as I am sure this isn't the most effective way to do it. Thanks!

Edit: added the process function that was previous missing. Also for clarification I am using regular JSON arrays and objects that usually exceed 100 objects in the array. If you want an example of what that data could look like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON#Example has a good structure of some of the data I am parsing (containing both objects and arrays).

Comment: What methods have you tried? I could be wrong, but `for... in` I think is slower than other methods, like a straight `for(let x = 0; x < length; x++)` method. To clean this up, you may want to look at a simple template engine like mustache. That would remove your html and probably do most of the heavy lifting.

Comment: You are right with the `for...in` statement, they are generally slower. I tested moving it to a standard loop, but it seems like the major break is the check if its an array or object.

Comment: I think you're right. Is it a possibility to cast everything as desired type instead of checking? Or use the old `JSON.parse(JSON.strigify(obj))` as a cast method?

Comment: Or use `Object.keys(obj).map()` instead of checks.

Comment: 110ms is very slow, but that will depend on the number of items being processed. You have not provided that information also there is a function in `ObjectString` that you have not provided `process`. As it looks 110ms would produce a huge string containing too many elements to be practical. Are you sure the problem in your functions and not the DOM parsing the HTML you have created?

Comment: I edited the post with more details (including the missing function). From testing and not running parts of the loop the best that I can tell is that the DOM is not the cause (as its not added until the end) and checking if its an array or object is the slow down. Using both `Array.isArray()` and `typeof` cause a slowing of the loop.

Comment: `isArray` and `typeof` can execute millions of times in 110ms and not the cause of the slowdown.  It is the DOM as you create a div and then add HTML to it in `process`. That will be very slow, also the function `format` what ever it does? could make it even worse

Comment: the process function only runs when there is an html string given. Most of the time this function is not used, but just to fix/close any tags. If I comment out the part that deals with arrays it runs faster. I have tested this and gotten a time of the array test to take ~0.03 seconds.

Comment: Doing another test of the parsing of data, I can say that the process function takes about ~0.002 seconds on average. All this function does is create a node, pretty print it, then return it as its been pretty printed. It will only run when it finds that the data contains html tags. So most of the time its skipped, however isArray and typeof are taking 2-3 times longer than the parsing of the DOM (which normally doesn't make sense, but its doing it that way). I also tested checking the first character from Ranger's method, didn't change the speed much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Continuous repetitive string concatenation is bad for performance because each such operation requires re-hashing of the string due to [String interning](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).
- **Array** enumeration using `for-in` loop is slower than `for-of` or a standard `for` loop.
- Things like `obj[key][subkey]` may be slow in a long loop so cache them in a variable.
- Do the proper performance measurements using [Devtools Timeline profiler](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference) to find bottlenecks.

---

Here's an arguably more readable and hopefully faster example:

```
const parts = [];
const group = obj[key];

if (Array.isArray(group)) {
  for (const val of group) {
    if (parts.length) parts.push(', ');
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      const tooLong = group.length > 10;
      const len = (tooLong ? group : val).length;
      parts.push(`<font color="green">Array(${len})</font>`);
      if (tooLong) break;
    } else {
      parts.push(objectPreview(val));
    }
  }
} else {
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(group)) {
    parts.push(`${parts.length ? ', ' : ''}${key}: ${
      Array.isArray(val) ? '[...]' : objectPreview(val)
    }`);
  }
}
const replacements = parts.join('');
```

```
function objectPreview(obj) {
  let str = obj;
  switch (typeof obj) {
    case 'object':
      str = '{...}';
      break;
    case 'string':
      if (/<.*?>/.test(obj)) {
        str = type === 'normal' ?
          `<pre>${process(obj).replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')}</pre>${obj}` :
          '<font color="red">"..."</font>';
      } else {
        str = `<font color="red">"${obj}"</font>`;
      }
      break;
    case 'number':
    case 'boolean':
      str = `<font color="#947cf6">${obj}</font>`;
      break;
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that calling things like `obj[key][subkey]` caused slowdown's like it has. I will keep this in mind in the future. I also didn't think about using Template literals inside my code would clean it up that much, I will also keep this in mind for the future. And the switch case for readability was also something I didn't think of (since its easier to read and maintain in this form). With testing performance of 400+ entries (the most I encounter) I see no slow down. Thanks!